# Supremum of $\alpha^2 z^\gamma/(\alpha + z)^2$ for $\gamma \in (0, 2)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I want to calculate $\sup\limits_{z} \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + z} \right)^2 z^{\gamma}$ for $\gamma \in (0, 2)$. I know that the solution is $z = \dfrac{\gamma \alpha}{2 - \gamma}$ but I don't know how to get it. My idea is to build the first derivative. So if we define $f(z) = \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + z} \right)^2 z^{\gamma}$, we have $f ' (z) = \left( \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + z} \right)^2 \gamma z^{\gamma - 1} - \dfrac{2 \alpha^2 z^{\gamma}}{(\alpha + z)^3}$. Now we can set $f'(z) = 0$ and solve it for $z$. But this seems difficult with all the $\gamma$...

Comment: Is not that hard, try to  write the equation, most of the terms can be canceled

Comment: To see it easier, consider $f'(z)/f(z)$ instead of just $f'(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just
(changing the notation a bit)
$f(x)
=\dfrac{z^g}{(a+z)^2}
$.

All we need here
is the quotient rule.

$\begin{array}\\
f'(z)
&=\dfrac{(a+z)^2gz^{g-1}-2(a+z)z^g}{(a+z)^4}\\
&=z^{g-1}\dfrac{(a+z)g-2z}{(a+z)^3}\\
\end{array}
$

This has an extreme when
$0
=(a+z)g-2z
=ag+z(g-2)
$
so
$z
=\dfrac{ag}{2-g}
$.